# Firebase database conection with Yii2

Tags: php, yii, firebase-realtime-database

I am having question about firebase database. can i connect firebase database with Yii2 application?

Dose it possible or need to take other way for that and if possible then how can i implement it.

Answer (score 0):

By default yii2 does not have support for firebase.
It does support SQLite, MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQL Server and Oracle. However there might be an extension for firebase support.

Comment: do you know any extension that i can use with yii?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not aware of any official extensions that would support it. You might consider hacking it together yourself but I don't know how big of a task this might be.

Here's debate about it on [github](https://github.com/schmunk42/yii2-extension-requests/issues/13). Apparently Laravel supports it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Yii2-firebase extension at https://github.com/grptx/yii2-firebase to connect to firebase or you can use firebase manual at https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#php_4 how to use Cloud Firestore using PHP.